# fill random() into text field when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field in my form and a submit button. As soon as submit button is clicked, I would like to fill this text field value with random number by using Math.rand() but it did not work, please help:

Here is my form:

```
<form id='testForm' method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" id= "randnum" name="randnum" value="">
    <input type ="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$('#testForm').submit(function(e) {
    document.getElementById('randnum').value = Math.random();
});
```

When form is submitted, The $_POST['randnum'] variable is still nothing? Please help...

Comment: Your JS code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/1vuj8gvv/. Can you show your PHP code where the value is empty?

Comment: Can you pls tell me the scenario..i mean why did you use text box for that.while submitting the button,you can pass the random number through ajax

Answer (score 1):

Make `value` equal to random on `input[type=submit]` click, Then form will also get submitted.

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
document.getElementById('randnum').value = Math.random();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use input type button instead of submit.[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1gsub6c7/6/)

```
<form id='testForm' method="post" action="process.php">
 <input type="text" id= "randnum" name="randnum" value="">
 <input type ="button" value="Submit" id="sbmt">
</form>
```

Use click event and then submit

```
$('#sbmt').click(function(e) {
document.getElementById('randnum').value = Math.random();
alert(document.getElementById('randnum').value);

    $("#testForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Even if i click on the text field the form is submitted ... that is not what the op asked .

Comment: @Alexander , my bad , pls check now I updated ansewer . It happend becuase of multitasking, sorry about it.

Answer (score -1):

HTML :

```
 <form id="testForm" method="post" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" id= "randnum" name="randnum" value="">
    <input type ="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
$('#testForm').click(function(e) {
    document.getElementById('randnum').value = Math.random();
});
```